# video upload in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying a demo for video upload in php but i am getting error as

> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\upp\upload_file.php on line 3
>   Call Stack

files are as follows:

abcd.html

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

upload_file.php

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("wmv","avi","mpeg","mpg");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/avi")|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/wmv")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mpg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>

enter code here
```

when i tried for image upload it works but for uploading video i changed file type in php code so it gives the above error

Comment: How big is the video file? Sometimes, if the uploaded file exceeds your server's file upload limits, it doesn't populate the $_FILES array with anything.

Comment: ya i already set max uploading size to 50mb in php.ini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get 'undefined index' in $_FILE, then PHP, Apache or a security tool (e.g. suhosin, apparmor) are blocking the upload, in order of likelyhood. The latter two will mainly apply as soon as you put your code on a linux production server, so we'll focus on the first.

Create a file in the same directory and put this code in it:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Then look for these settings:

```
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
```

If they are smaller than your video, you have your first setting to change.

Find php.ini in your wamp directory with windows search, and change the lines to something like this:

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

Then stop and start Apache and check phpinfo if the values increased. If they did, your upload should work.

If the values change but the upload still doesn't work, search for httpd.conf and find the value of LimitRequestBody, increase it, and restart Apache.

Comment: If in Apache, most likely [`LimitRequestBody`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)

Comment: @Wrikken Nice. Edited accordingly.

Comment: i edited upload_max_filesize and post_max_size to 100M but when i when i run the file with phpinfo() it shows previous values for this fields.

Comment: i have modified the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size field values to 100M. modification are visible in php.ini file but when i run a php file with phpinfo() function there it shows previous values only

Comment: Did you restart the Apache server in your WAMP control panel?

Comment: yeah but still not working.

Comment: Please verify you are editing the right configuration file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26719/discussion-between-cmc-and-jayesh-naik)

Answer (score 1):

The error you are geeting is because of php code is getting running even if form is not submitting. So in starting no array is populated since you have not uploaded any file.
Infact it is a warning not an error

Check if form is submitted or or not .. using isset($_POST['submit'])

Secondly I will suggest you to optimize the code .. if you checking file types no need to check the extension ..

I have modified you code a bit .. Try it and have a look

```
                   <?php
            $is_form_submitted =  (isset($_POST['submit']))?true:false;

        if($is_form_submitted)
        {

            $allowedTypes   = array("video/wmv","video/avi","video/mpeg","video/mpg",'video/mp4');
            $is_valid_type  = (in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $allowedTypes))?true:false;
           if ( $is_valid_type&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000))
          {
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
            {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
            else
            {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
              {
              echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
              }
            else
              {
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
              "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
              echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
              }
            }
          }
        else
        {
          echo "Invalid file";
         }

        }
                ?>
```

SUGGESTION

check following php_ini setting before any upload

```
file_uploads
upload_max_filesize
max_input_time
memory_limit
max_execution_time
post_max_size
```

ref : http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php

Comment: i have used your modified code but whenever i submit button it is redirected to upload_file.php with no content no warnings no error

Comment: where have you written this code ?

Comment: main problem is that i have modified the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size field values to 100M. modification are visible in php.ini file but when i run a php file with phpinfo() function there it shows previous values only

Comment: @Jayesh_naik You might be missing something .. working perfectly with me .... try turning on error_reporting() and check your syntax

Comment: restart httpd (apache) service then.

Comment: thanks finally modification are done, but whichever video format file  im trying to upload it dhows invalid file only

Comment: try to check the file size .... its can be obly reason now

Comment: thank you very much i had done modification in different file. now i made correction and it works